# Is there a way to check which app is turning on the VPN service?

Tags: android, vpn

I want to avoid all vpn connections except the one that my app creates it, so I am using the following code:

```
public static boolean vpn() {
        String iface = "";
        try {
            for (NetworkInterface networkInterface : Collections.list(NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces())) {
                if (networkInterface.isUp())
                    iface = networkInterface.getName();
                Log.d("DEBUG", "IFACE NAME: " + iface);
                if ( iface.contains("tun") || iface.contains("ppp") || iface.contains("pptp")) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        } catch (SocketException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        return false;
    }
```

This works fine to detect if the VPN is used or not, but I want also to check if the app that turned on this VPN is mine or not, so I just want to know if there is a way to get the package name of the app that turned this VPN on.

I tried this with the Sharepreferences but I am using a timer to check it every 1 second and this makes problems sometimes if turning on and saving to shared preferences that could be delayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there was no answers, here is how I've solved this issue:

- Every time I turn my app VPN on, I save this as a boolean to the Shared preferences.
- I set a timer to check for VPN connected or not every 5 seconds and check with an `if statement` of the values of the share preferences.